# Rerouting outgoing WAN traffic to local PC in LAN

Tags: windows, routing

I want traffic outgoing to some IP in WAN to be redirrected to local PC in LAN. For example, traffic to IP 1.2.3.4 (WAN) would be redirrected to 192.168.0.3 (to my lan computer). Router model is D-Link DI-524, but I don't think it's possible to set this up within that router. Every idea is welcome, for example connecting device trough ad-hoc to my local machine and serving requests to desired IP dirrectly (but how?) or setting up some proxy server. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a managed switch in the middle and forward all requests to IP x to IP y. Other than that, I am at a loss. A proxy might work, but it might prevent internet access for the subnet. I'll keep thinking.

Comment: nice idea, but I need pure software solution (no extra switches, hubs, etc...)

Comment: You could try a powerful free firewall that might be able to reassign outbound packet headers. Commodo might work.

Comment: do you know the setting name in the firewall, or some group of settings?

Comment: It would be a port forwarding rule i imagine. All outgoing to IP x on port 80 to IP y on port 80

Comment: Port 80 for web traffic of course... any other port for whatever you need.

Comment: I can't do anything with the machine which I want to have redirect, sorry if I declared it badly.

Comment: It will have to be on the machine sending the request or a switch. Otherwise you are SOL.